# Dynamically adding a tab in bootstrap doesn't show tab-pane content after navigating away and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ive seen a lot of similar questions, but nothing that is quite like this (that I can find).

This is in a rails 5 app, bootstrap-sass 3.3, jquery 1.12.4.

```
$("#opendata").on("click", function(){
  $("<div class='tab-pane active' id='summary'>hi</div>").appendTo("#tab-content");
  $("<li class='active' data-toggle='tab'><a href='summary' aria-expanded='true'>Summary</a></li>").appendTo("#tabs")
 })
```

I have 2 tabs that are loaded with the page, and need to add other tabs dynamically.  The above code works - the tab is added, and the tab-pane contents are displayed.  However if I navigate away from that tab, and navigate back (the tab itself will go active) the tab-pane is showing the contents of the previous tab.

I've narrowed the issue down to the dynamic tab-pane not getting an 'active' class put on it.  I've tried to do this via console as well, and it doesn't work either.

The main solution I saw for dynamic tabs was to add something like this

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  })
})
```

But to no avail.  It seems like the added tab-pane just doesn't respond to anything, console or otherwise.  Am I missing something or going about this the wrong way?  The tab gets added fine, just when navigating away and back that it doesn't respond.

Comment: Have you tried showing the tabs by directly calling it's id? `$('#summary').tab('show')` . `$("tabs")` seems like it might be the wrong selector.

Comment: I did - for both the tabs that are loaded with the page, as well as the dynamically added tabs.  Didn't work for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

so chalk this one up to looking at the same code for too long on my part.  The solution is:

```
$("<li class='active' data-toggle='tab'><a href='#summary' aria-expanded='true'>Summary</a></li>").appendTo("#tabs")
```

Notice the '#' in front of the href that I forgot in the first post.